# PLCrashReporter framework not working

Tags: objective-c, plcrashreporter

I am trying to make a sample application (for mac) using the **PLCrashReporter** framework and the application works fine on my system but the application crashes on the other systems as the systems don't have that framework.Please let me know how to add the framework on other systems through our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to go to Build Phase and then set the destination to framework and drag framework from your Xcode project to copy files and remove it from link Binery with Libraries and now go ahead and make your build it is ready to distribute.......